# How do I convert this sql to a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How do I convert the following query into linq to sql query?

```
    select 
invoice.id, web_users.id, web_users.first_name, web_users.last_name,web_users.email_address 
from attendees,web_users
join invoice where attendees.invoice_id=invoice.id and invoice.seminar_id=6 and attendees.web_user_id=web_users.id
```

this is what I had but it is throwing an error:

```
from att in context.Attendees
                          from webUsers in context.WebUsers
                          join invoice in context.Invoice
                          on att.InvoiceID equals invoice.ID                          
                          where invoice.SeminarID == seminarId &&
                          webUsers.ID == att.WebUserID                                       
                          select new
                          {
                              webUsers.FirstName,
                              att.InvoiceID                                                       
                          };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What specifically is the error message?

Comment: The error message is: Argument type 'DbLinq.Data.Linq.Table`1[WebUsers]' does not match the corresponding member type 'WebUsers'

Comment: It amuses me that people are always trying to convert from TSQL to LINQ, when I spend so much of my time converting from LINQ to fixed TSQL....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
from att in context.Attendees
                          join webUsers in context.WebUsers
on att.web_user_id equals webUsers.id
                          join invoice in context.Invoice
                          on att.InvoiceID equals invoice.ID                          
                          where invoice.SeminarID == seminarId                                       
                          select new
                          {
                              webUsers.FirstName,
                              att.InvoiceID                                                       
                          };
```

Comment: No worries. Glad I can be of help. :)

Comment: @majid, show your appreciation with up votes on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Start by cleaning up the SQL. Don't mix joins and implicit joins in the query, use explicit joins for both:

```
select invoice.id, web_users.id, web_users.first_name, web_users.last_name,web_users.email_address 
from attendees
inner join web_users on web_users.id = attendees.web_user_id
inner join invoice on invoice.id = attendees.invoice_id
where invoice.seminar_id = 6
```

Now I think that it translates:

```
from att in context.Attendees
join webUsers in context.WebUsers on webUsers.ID equals att.WebUserID
join invoice in context.Invoice on att.InvoiceID equals invoice.ID
where invoice.SeminarID == seminarId
select new {
  webUsers.FirstName,
  att.InvoiceID                                                       
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  That is sound advice.  The other answer by ysrb was first so it was my accepted answer